# Django admin not serving static files on Apache

Tags: django, apache, django-staticfiles

I've seen similar questions but they are more than 4 years old and the answers doesn't work anymore. I have a site that works correctly on Apache, except for the admin staticfiles. The staticfiles work fine with Django's runserver. I'm kind of lost here, any advice will help.

Comment: Did you do `collectstatic` on the Apache vhost?

Comment: @AndreyShipilov Thanks for your answer ... run python manage.py collectstatic? I did.

Comment: And you see the files are being collected into STATIC_ROOT directory and there's an admin directory in there?

Comment: @AndreyShipilov No, there is not an admin directory there.

Comment: This means collectstatic didn't collect the files. Are you using different settings.py for development and Apache deployed environment?

Comment: Did you figure out what was it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you serve static files using apache, static folder is supposed to be in your /var/www/html directory. I had gone through same scenario as yours. collectstatic didnt work for me. What I did was, `copied static contents of admin app to /var/www/html/static/admin`. This admin directory contains four other directories `css, fonts, img and js`. In my case apache setup was the default so /var/www/html was my public directory. Following can be used for reference.

```
server
    |
    -var
       | 
        -www
            |
             -html
                  |
                  - static
                         |
                         -admin
                               |-css
                               |-fonts
                               |-img
                               |-js
```

You can try aforementioned approach. It would be helpful if you let know issue is resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Check the following things

1)Did you add STATIC_ROOT in settings file?

2)After activating the virtual environment(if any), did you run

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```